# Python 3.4 printing greek characters - Firefox - Win 7 - IIS web server

Tags: encoding, python-3.4

Here is my code

```
    print('Status: 200 OK')
    print('Content-Type: text/html;')
    print('')
    a = "Κέτσαπ - Συστατικά: Πάστα τομάτας"
    print(a)
```

This is the error I get

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\karomi_website\test\python
    \greek.py", line 8, in print(a) File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in
    encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: 
    character maps to
```

Is there something in IIS I need to do?

Tried print(sys.getdefaultencoding()) and its UTF-8. So I am not sure where the cp1252 is coming from?

Comment: Your default encoding is set to cp1252, so you can't `print()` non-Latin characters. The good news is this is a great excuse to stop trying to use 1996-era technology and move to a WSGI framework. No one should be writing CGI in 2014, and any good framework will make this work seamlessly.

Comment: Point taken on the WSGI. Have started exploring Django. But is there a way to make the above code work?